# peculiar inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have two values $\alpha_1 \in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$, and $\alpha_2 \in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$.  Defining a new value $\alpha_{12} := \frac{\alpha_1}{1+k} + \frac{\alpha_2}{1+1/k}$, where $k := \frac{A_2}{A_1}$ with $A_1,\,A_2 > 0$, I want to show that for all $k>0$, the following holds true:
\begin{equation}
\alpha_{12}(1-\alpha_{12})(A_1 + A_2)^2 > \alpha_1(1-\alpha_1)A_1^2 +  \alpha_2(1-\alpha_2)A_2^2.
\end{equation} 
For $k=1$, i.e., $A_1 = A_2$, the above inequality boils down to:
\begin{equation}
A_1^2 (\alpha_1(1-2\alpha_2) + \alpha_2) > 0
\end{equation}
which is true as $\alpha_2 < \frac{1}{2}$. Now, I do not know how to show that the inequality holds for all $k>0$. Based on the symmetry of the problem, if we can show that the inequality holds for $0<k<1$, then we are done. As the other case $k>1$ can be shown similarly.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Using the notation $x=\alpha_1, y=\alpha_2, a=A_1, b=A_2,k=\frac ba$ and $z=\alpha_{12}$, note that we actually have $$z=\frac{a x + b y}{a+b}.$$ Hence, $$\alpha_{12}(1-\alpha_{12})(A_1 + A_2)^2 - \alpha_1(1-\alpha_1)A_1^2 -  \alpha_2(1-\alpha_2)A_2^2=-a^2 (1-x) x+(a+b) (a x+b y) \left(1-\frac{a x+b y}{a+b}\right)-b^2 (1-y) y=a b (-2 x y+x+y)$$

Comment: Can you finish it now?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Thank you very much for the prompt response! I definitely can finish it now as $x+y-2xy > 0$. Thank You!

Comment: You are welcome 